# Pandas 19 not parsing dates

Tags: python, pandas

A script I'd written using an earlier version of Pandas now no longer works. Date parsing is not working.  This is my `read_html` line:

```
gnu = pd.read_html('gnucash.html', flavor="html5lib", header=0, parse_dates=['Date'])
```

Pandas identifies the HTML table properly but returns the date as unicode.  The HTML has been generated by Gnucash and is in ISO format `Y-m-d` (no times).

Whatever I do I can't get Pandas to recognise the dates.  I tried including a `date_parser`, but `read_html` doesn't recognise that.

Apologies @IanS, I've inadvertently deleted your comment.  When I set out an example it worked.  I think the problem is with my html file.  There must be a non-date buried in the date column.  Anyway, Pandas did what it ought to with my sample file.

Thanks for taking an interest.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: Apologies @IanS, I've inadvertently deleted your comment. When I set out an example it worked. I think the problem is with my html file. There must be a non-date buried in the date column. Anyway, Pandas did what it ought to with my sample file.

Comment: If you want to work with python/pandas and gnucash, you may be interested by my piecash package http://piecash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you @sdementen.  I am trying piecash.  One thing I cannot fathom is how to produce a df from the sub accounts of a main one.  I have a series of expense account groupings which I need to produce df for.

Comment: Have you try the function splits_df http://piecash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/piecash.core.book.html#piecash.core.book.Book.splits_df ? Is it more or less what you want?

Comment: Thanks again @sdementen.  I did try that but it returned only the guid.  As the gnucash file is now in mysql format I'm just using sql interrogation which is sufficient for my needs.